# Prevent object from being extended

Tags: ruby, module

I have a module that provides some lazy lookup via dot syntax for hashes:

```
module DotHash
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    # look for keys...
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, _include_all = nil)
    # some logic
  end
end
```

I ran into the problem of accidentally extending `nil`:

```
# @hash == nil
@hash.extend(DotHash)
```

and this caused HUGE problems, because now `nil` has this `method_missing` logic which messes things up.

I though adding a hook would solve the problem:

```
module DotHash
  def self.extended(base)
    return if base.is_a?(Hash)
    raise "must be a hash"
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    # look for keys...
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, _include_all = nil)
    # some logic
  end
end
```

And indeed, it throws an error:

```
[1] pry(main)> nil.extend(DotHash)
RuntimeError: must be a hash
```

But the logic got added anyway:

```
[2] pry(main)> nil.foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
    9707: from bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
    9706: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    9705: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    9704: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    9703: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    9702: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    9701: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    9700: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     ... 9695 levels...
       4: from /usr/src/app/app/lib/dot_hash.rb:26:in `respond_to_missing?'
       3: from /usr/src/app/app/lib/dot_hash.rb:14:in `method_missing'
       2: from /usr/src/app/app/lib/dot_hash.rb:26:in `respond_to_missing?'
       1: from /usr/src/app/app/lib/dot_hash.rb:14:in `method_missing'
/usr/src/app/app/lib/mapper/dot_hash.rb:26:in `respond_to_missing?': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Is there a hook that get's triggered **BEFORE** the object is extended, and not after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`extend_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#extend_object-method): (the docs contain a similar example)

> Extends the specified object by adding this module's constants and methods (which are added as singleton methods). This is the callback method used by `Object#extend`.

```
module DotHash
  def self.extend_object(obj)
    raise TypeError, 'must be a hash' unless obj.is_a?(Hash)
    
    super
  end

  def foo
    123
  end
end

h = {}
h.extend(DotHash)
h.foo #=> 123

n = nil
n.extend(DotHash) # TypeError: must be a hash
n.foo             # NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass
```